# Как определить находится ли курсор в виджете?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, eventfilter, qevent

Необходимо определять когда курсор с `event`-ом удержания левой кнопки мыши переходит в другой виджет и в какой точке (`x, y`) он это делает. 
См. пример . . .

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as QW
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt   

class Example(QW.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        
    def main_setup(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.setWindowTitle("Example :)")
        self.setGeometry(x, y, width, height)
        

    def ui_setup(self):
        self.TheFrame = QW.QFrame(self)
        self.TheFrame.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 150)  
        self.TheFrame.setStyleSheet('background-color : red')  
        
        
    def Code(self, x = 0, y = 0):  # < --- Какой - то код ,который будет выводить x , y
        pass
        
        
    def keyPressEvent(self, e):  # < - - - Это просто имитация :)
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_F3:
            self.setWindowTitle('!!! x = чему-то, y = чему-то')
    

app = QW.QApplication(sys.argv)
widgets = Example()
widgets.main_setup(0, 0, 500, 300)
widgets.ui_setup()
widgets.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: Вывод]

P.S. Если вы знаете хорошую статью, которая объясняет по какому принципу работают события мышки в *PyQt5*, то прошу оставить ссылку. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен что правильно понял то, что вы хотите сделать и где вы хотите кликнуть  ЛКМ.

Для себя я понял вашу задачу так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QFrame, QApplication, \
        QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QObject, pyqtSignal, QPoint,  \
        QEvent, pyqtSlot
        

class MouseTracker(QObject):
    positionChanged = pyqtSignal(QPoint)

    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__(widget)
        self._widget = widget
        self.widget.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.widget.installEventFilter(self)

    @property
    def widget(self):
        return self._widget

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.widget and event.type() == QEvent.MouseMove:
            self.positionChanged.emit(event.pos())
        elif event.type() == QEvent.Leave:
            self.positionChanged.emit(QPoint(-30, -30))
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
 

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.theFrame = QFrame(self)
        self.theFrame.setStyleSheet('background-color : red')  
        
        tracker = MouseTracker(self.theFrame)
        tracker.positionChanged.connect(self.on_positionChanged)

        self.frame_2 = QFrame(self)
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet('background-color : #E0D98C') 
        
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)                           # + 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.theFrame)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.frame_2)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)

        self.label_position = QLabel(self.theFrame, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_position.setStyleSheet(
            'background-color: white; border: 1px solid black')
        self.label_position.hide()            

    @pyqtSlot(QPoint)
    def on_positionChanged(self, pos):
        if pos.y() < 20 and (pos.x() > self.width() - 100):
            delta = QPoint(-60, 15)
        elif pos.y() < 20:
            delta = QPoint(30, 15)
        elif pos.x() > self.width() - 100:
            delta = QPoint(-60, -15)     
        else:
            delta = QPoint(30, -15)
        self.label_position.show()
        self.label_position.move(pos + delta)
        self.label_position.setText(f"({pos.x()}, {pos.y()})")
        self.label_position.adjustSize()
   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.setWindowTitle("Example :)")
    w.resize(500, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да вы всё верно поняли. Решение отличное! Благодарю за помощь.